# Enable "double tap to wake" programmatically on Asus device

Tags: android

On Asus Zenfone devices there is a setting to enable `Double tap to wake` feature in `Advanced settings > ZenMotion` category.

Is it possible to enable this kind of manufacturer-specific settings programmatically ? (provided the app has `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission)

Or is it possible, at least, to detect if the feature is enabled ?

NB: when enabling it manually I can see the following logs:

```
2019-12-12 17:42:25.954 17750-17750/? D/AsusGesturesFileSetValue: getGesturesAlphabetValue: 1111111
2019-12-12 17:42:25.954 17750-17750/? D/AsusGesturesFileSetValue: getGesturesDoubleSwitch: 1
2019-12-12 17:42:25.955 17750-17750/? D/AsusGesturesFileSetValue: getGesturesSwipeSwitch: 0
2019-12-12 17:42:25.955 17750-17750/? D/AsusGesturesFileSetValue: setDriverGesturesItemSwitch: gestureValue 10111111
2019-12-12 17:42:25.955 17750-17750/? D/AsusGesturesFileSetValue: setDriverGesturesItemSwitch: st 10111111
```

Comment: Only if the manufacturer actually stores the value where you can access it. AFAIK, there is no technical requirement for things that appear in the Settings app to be stored in the `Settings` provider.

Comment: If I register a content observer on `Settings.System.CONTENT_URI` I can see changes on `content://settings/system/asus_motion_gesture_settings` when changing these settings manually. Does it mean I could somehow update it programmatically ?

Comment: In theory. In practice, `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`. That `Uri` suggests it would be modified akin to the others [in `Settings.System`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System).